Pull a random value from an array and insert it into the paragraph element
I am trying to fetch the list of words from an external .txt file and put them into a javascript array, after which to pull a random word from that array and insert it into a paragraph element.
The words.txt:
"word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word6"

HTML and Javascript:
<div><p id="word"></p></div>
<script>
         var wordList = fetch("/js/words.txt");
         var words = Array(wordList);
         const randomWord = Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length);
         function word() { document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = randomWord; }
</script>

When I load the webpage, it's empty. There is no words in the paragraph element. What's the issue?

Are you serving this HTML/JavaScript and the supporting text file with a local HTTP web server? What errors are you seeing in your developer console? Can you provide them as part of your [mre]?

fetch is async, your wordList in your code is a promise which may fullfill at some time (and possibily your server might not actually allow you to serve txt files)

You define word() but never actually invoke it; why?

randomWord is only set once, so it will grab the first random word and use that each time word() is called.

@esqew No, I am using a built in code editor on my hosting provider's website. I does not show any errors.

Isn't the function invoked automatically?

@mykaf isn't it going to choose a random one each time?

Each time you load the page. Why would randomWord  get set more than once?

You defined your function, but haven't called it. How would the page know to invoke it?

The issue is that you're not handling the asynchronous nature of the fetch function correctly. The fetch function returns a Promise that resolves to the response of the HTTP request. You need to handle this Promise and extract the text content from the response before you can use it.
you can do it like this:
`
 <div><p id="word"></p></div>
    <script>
        fetch('/js/words.txt")
            .then(response => response.text()) 
            .then(text => {

                var wordList = text.split(", ");                                
                const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length);                
                const randomWord = wordList[randomIndex];
                
                document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = randomWord;
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching words:', error));
    </script>

`
This code fetches the content of the "words.txt" file, splits it into an array of words using split(", "), generates a random index to pick a word from the array, and finally displays the random word in the paragraph element.
Make sure to adjust the file path "/js/words.txt" to the correct location of your "words.txt" file. Additionally, ensure that your server is configured to serve ".txt" files correctly.

Did you generate (a part of) this answer using a tool like ChatGPT?

no, I wrote this code :)

It did work! Though, because the words are split by "," it displays the word together with the quotation marks, however, that's fixable on my side. Thank you!
